# Is there a way to hook a custom handler to debugger events like break in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, visual-studio-debugging

I have a C# application (.NET Framework 4.8) that receives a stream of UDP packets and monitors the stream to ensure no packets are dropped (they contain sequence numbers) and that the packets arrive in a timely manner.  Debugging the application causes nuisance warnings as packets are dropped while execution is paused.  I am looking for a way to attach my own handler to debugger events just before breaking and just after resuming to account for this and suppress the warnings.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to overcomplicate things. Could you describe the problem a bit further? Why do those warnings matter if you're debugging? Do you have some code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Are these warnings being emitted by the debugger (as opposed to the application code)?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, no they are emitted by my application code, so I can choose to not emit them if I can figure out that the packets were dropped because the debugger paused the program (as opposed to e.g. dropped in transit).  So I'm looking for a way to record the fact that a break point is about to be hit (or resume) , like an event or callback.